# Create Sharepoint folder from VBA (access 2016)

Tags: vba, sharepoint-online

I have an access 2016 app that currently creates a folder on a shared drive related to the DB record the user is working on.

We are migrating to SP online and I need to re-create something similar

I can list the files and folders currently in a directory using the API but when I try and create a new folder I am getting an error

`"{"error":{"code":"-2130575251, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The security validation for this page is invalid and might be corrupted. Please use your web browser's Back button to try your operation again."}}}"`

The only thing I can see I am doing differently is I am not including a Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken header in the post.

I haven't been including it in the gets for the Files list and it is working using the cached credentials from IE.

Getting the file and folder like this is working

```
    'create XML HTTP object
    Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

    With objXMLHTTP

        'open connection to site
        .Open "GET", url, False
        '.send

        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json"
        .send

        Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

        sJSONString = .responseText

    End With


    Dim Json As Object
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(sJSONString)
    Debug.Print JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(Json, Whitespace:=2)

    Dim value As Dictionary

    For Each value In Json("value")
        Debug.Print "> " + value("Name")
    Next value
```

However trying to create a folder fails

```
    strPostData = "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Folder' }, 'ServerRelativeUrl': '/Shared Documents/Folder1'}"

    'Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP
    With objXMLHTTP
        .Open "POST", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "accept", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json;odata=verbose"
        .send strPostData
        strResponse = .responseText
    End With
```

Can anyone advise if what I am trying is possible and if so what I am doing is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, almost immediately I found and answer!

Needed to add

```
        .setRequestHeader "X-RequestDigest", digest
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(strPostData)
```

and it all started working!

Thanks anyway, hope this helps someone else

Comment: Hi Robert - I've been looking for a good example of this type of thing (we are gradually moving to SP online, and drive mapping/syncing is not a reliable workaround).  Would you be willing/able to share more of your code, since it seems like you have it figured out?

Comment: Hi Tim,

I never got it to work in an acceptable/reliable way direct from access/VBA.

What we ended up doing was when the user clicked we actually opened up an internal PHP web site running Laravel. Under the covers this used the Office365 PHP library to check for the folder/path and create them as required.

Finally the user would be redirected to the Sharepoint URL

This has been working well for us for a couple of years now.

Hope that helps!

Rob

Comment: OK thanks for the info Robert - seems like we're really not invited to work with SharePoint via VBA  